# VB application does not return same list in two computer

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6

I have a program that use MSSQL 2005. My problem is that this app is wrote with VB6 and when I get `customer list` in a computer it return 6000 rows and it is correct. But when I get customer list with another computer with same MSSQL(2005) and same OS (Windows XP). what can I do to solve this problem? 
Thanks in advanced.
**EDIT**
The query is simple and it is:

```
SELECT * FROM Buyer
```

I think, maybe the problem is in indexing, clustered, SATA3 HDD or something else.

This is Design of the table what I was speaking about it:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Buyer](
[BuyerCode] [nvarchar](10) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[Atbar] [money] NULL,
[AddB] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
[Tel] [nvarchar](200) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
[CityCode] [nvarchar](6) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[CityName] [nvarchar](35) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
[TBLO] [nvarchar](150) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
[SKH] [nvarchar](15) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
[NP] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
[CodeAG] [nvarchar](20) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
[CodeSF] [nvarchar](2) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[NameSF] [nvarchar](70) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
[KindM] [nvarchar](15) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
[VAZ] [bit] NOT NULL,
[name] [nvarchar](250) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
[vazk] [bit] NULL,
[Tozeh] [nvarchar](350) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Buyer_Tozeh]  DEFAULT (N''),
[Tozehp] [nvarchar](350) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Buyer_Tozehp]  DEFAULT (N''),
[Onvan] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
[GhK] [smallint] NULL,
[AutoFCode] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Buyer_AutoFCode]  DEFAULT ((1)),
[CodeF] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
[NameF] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
[DateF] [char](10) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Buyer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BuyerCode] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Comment: Is it the same database? Is it being run at the same time?

Comment: yes it is. It's running with the same data.

Comment: Any change it's permission based? E.g. depending on which user logs on - they get access to different data

Comment: no, it isn't related to permission. it was working with the one user for all time.

Comment: What's the query? What's the app look like? Not enough info here.

Comment: The app is an Accounting Software in VB6 Language and the query that I get it from `SQL Server Profiler` is a simple `SELECT`. If you need I can send you SELECT Query.

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to include that query.

Comment: You have different numbers of row than 6000, or what are the differences?

Comment: IF you're doing a `select *` on two different machines at the same time and getting different results then they are touching different databases.

Comment: The correct numbers of row is 9999 But one PC shows different from other.

Comment: No @Zane I'm sure that the database is the same. The problem is in showing SELECT query in two PCs.

Comment: How do you connect with the Db? With ODBC?

Comment: No @StefanoBafaro . its OLE DB connection.

Comment: Is it 9999 or 6000? Both numbers look suspicious anyway. Check and compare the connections strings from the 2 instances of the program.

Comment: If you are querying the same database server and the same database it WILL NOT return different results to different PC's if they are using the same query.

Comment: You set the connection string with a kind of "config" file? If is true, be sure that the files are identical.

Comment: What is `Buyers`? Is it a table or a view?

Comment: The main problem is when I was checking the query with `MSSQL` Manager it return correct (9999) records but when I using it with Application It return 6000 records.

Comment: Post your connection strings.

Comment: Post also how do you call the query in VB6 code and how you manage the result, thanks.

Comment: Oh then your application is limiting the record set. Check your VB 6 code.

Comment: I have not access to VB code. this is compiled code. and the Buyer object is a table not view.

Comment: Where are shown the records in your software?

Comment: If the application is indeed limiting the result set, it should either have a setting to control the limiting number (which is now 6000) and/or some "`Next`" button to show you the next set (of 3999) rows.

Comment: @ypercube the program has not any limiting control and now button to show more rows. I think maybe problem is for Indexing or other

Comment: Indexes are not the problem. Ask your money back.

Comment: I have edited my question and add Table design.

Comment: This program is too old and  have not access to this option.

Comment: `Buyer` I have edited my question.

Comment: The index is irrelevant. That's not how indexing works. The problem is in your VB code. As far as SQL SERVER goes it doesn't get much simpler than `SELECT * FROM` whatever.

Comment: What type of Object in VB6 is displaying the list. I just recently did a VB6 update where the control couldnt do more then 6000 entries. Very likely the same reason here. Its probably a maximum for that control.

Comment: Wait. The problem is that your vendor software (that you don't have the source for) is returning a different number of rows than your own query? Do you have the actual SQL from the VB6 application? If not, then you have no way of knowing what it does with the query or results. We can't debug the VB6 application if you can't access the source for it.

Comment: @KenWhite I have the actual SQL from the VB6 application by checking it from SQL profiler.

Comment: @MajidDaeiNejad: But you have no idea what the VB6 is doing with it **afterward**, and we can't debug that for you because we can't know either. Is it filtering? Is the control doing the display simply not able to handle that many rows? We can't tell, any more than you can.

Comment: Thank you @logixologist .You guess right. I was installing old version of an object which the application couldn't show all of rows with this object.

Comment: @MajidDaeiNejad I posted it as an answer if you want to accept it to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently did a VB6 update where the control couldnt do more then 6000 entries. Very likely the same reason here. Its probably a maximum for that control. Check to see if you can either get an updated one if available (if its third party) or maybe use a different control.

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure your connection string is the same on both installs of your app (recompile if necessary)
- Ensure you're connecting to the same database on both machines (that is, ***not*** using localhost)
- Ensure your VB code isn't modifying the ResultsSet

Comment: According to my question comments, I said that connection is the same and database is backup and restore to other machine and It is the same too.